# Which wireless 3G cards work?

Tags: wireless, 3g

I'm running Ubuntu Maverick on a ThinkPad X201. Does anyone know what 3G wireless cards or USB dongles work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virgin mobile MC 760 mobile broadband usb air card,work just fine for me but you must install it on a windows or mac machine so that you can finish activation after you buy it. Make sure that the "usb-modeswitch"is installed,it will turn it on when you plug it in.